# Result code 7002 is returned when the AchievementsClient.getAchievementList API is called to obtain achievements

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

When I use the **HMS Core Game Service SDK** in **Andriod Studio**, why:

> result code 7002

is returned and log information:

> this player's game service is unavailable

generated when the **AchievementsClient.getAchievementList** API is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result code 7002 indicates a network error or incorrect service address setting on HUAWEI AppGallery. Ensure that the network connection is normal.

Then open HUAWEI AppGallery (10.3.x or later), go to Me > Settings > Game Services, enable HUAWEI Game Service, and agree to the privacy statement.

If a user who has not enabled HUAWEI Game Service queries achievement data, the game needs to instruct the user to enable HUAWEI Game Service.